# Use prelude-ls with LiveScript

Tags: javascript, livescript, prelude.ls

I just need to use prelude-ls library in LiveScript, but no from the REPL. In my little test, I have 4 files:

- main.htm
- application.ls
- application.js
- require.js

I have the latest version of `require.js` (2.1.15) and in my `main.htm` I load the scripts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./prelude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then, I go to my `application.ls` to test:

```
require! 'prelude-ls'

[1 2 3] |> prelude-ls.map (* 2)
```

My compile command is:

`lsc -cwd $myFilePath`
And it compiles just fine. Then, I go there to get the final result, to test and receive the following error:

`Uncaught Error: Module name "prelude-ls" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Well, I saw the this is a very common error and its corrections would happen in the **js** file, not in the **ls** and none of the links I followed solved my problems. I've tried it in 2 computers and had the really same result.

My final js file, `application.js` is:

```
// Generated by LiveScript 1.2.0
(function(){
  var preludeLs;
  preludeLs = require('prelude-ls');
  preludeLs.map((function(it){
    return it * 2;
  }))(
  [1, 2, 3]);
}).call(this);
```

Plase, help me if possible. I really read all the documentation of livescript and it doens't cites its first use with prelude-ls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing AMD.js (here, Require.JS) and CommonJS.
AMD.js uses the

```
require(['dep1', 'dep2'], function (dep1, dep2) {
  dep1.callSomething();
});
```

(this allows for async loading)

CommonJS (which is what prelude-ls uses), on the other hand, is basically what node does (and what we generate with `require!`):

```
var preludeLs = require('prelude-ls')
```

Comment: In use with commonJS I yet get the error that `require is not defined`. I tried `npm install requirejs` but didn't work.

Comment: You need to include the file on your page to get `require`. You might want to look at browserify

Answer (score 0):

At first I didn't understand, I find the answer confusing, though correct. Please let me sum it up.

Actually it's very simple and it works [as says the doc](http://www.preludels.com/#installation).

We must install `prelude-ls` with npm or bower. We need to include the file `prelude-browser.js` (at `prelude-ls/browser/prelude-browser.js`).

Then we just require prelude at the beginning of our code:

```
prelude = require 'prelude-ls'
```

and we can call `prelude.sum`, etc.

A second option is to import exactly the function we need, like so:

```
{map, filter, lines} = require 'prelude-ls'
```

so we can call them directly.

That works with gulp and angularjs FYI.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382364/how-to-run-prelude-functions?) is clear.